# Force a textarea to be on the same line with other elements

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a webpage with the following layout:

```
Text            
Radio Button    
Radio Button    
Button
```

I want to add a textarea that will be on the same line as the elements, like:

```
Text            **********
Radio Button    *Textarea*
Radio Button    **********
Button          **********
```

(the asterixes mark the place occupied by the textarea)

But it ends up being just under the elements:

```
Text            
Radio Button    
Radio Button    
Button          
**********
*Textarea*
**********
**********
```

What CSS styling should I apply to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to float your content or use the `inline-block` option

Here is an exemple of what you want:http://jsfiddle.net/uDLZF/3/

**CSS**

```
#first, #second{
    float:left;
}
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div>
        <ul id="first">
            <li>Text </li>     
            <li>Radio Button  </li> 
            <li>Radio Button  </li> 
            <li>Button </li>         
        </ul>
        <ul id="second">
            <li>**********</li>   
            <li>*Textarea*</li> 
            <li>**********</li> 
            <li>**********</li>         
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to float the textarea left or right depending on whichever works for you. Beware though, if you float the textarea right you will need to put the markup above the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest encapsulating your origin form elements in a div tag, so that they would be grouped together.  Then apply a float to that div and to your textarea.

```
<div style="float: left;">
    Text
    ...
    Button
<div>
<textarea style="float: left;"></textarea>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Use an element with clear:both to prevent the rest of the page's content (if any) from wrapping around your form elements.

Answer (score -1):

there are different methods:

1) using table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Text Goes here... </td>
    <td> Textarea goes here </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2) Floating the element to left direction

```
<div style="float:left"> Text goes here </div>
<textarea style="float:left"></textarea>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

3) Setting Inline-Block property

```
<div style="display: inline-block; "> Text goes here.. </div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Note: Set same height for both text area and text content div

Comment: That's not helping - beginners should be informed about the correct context in which certain elements can or cannot be used. In the case of tables, they should only be used to present tabulated data - and not for layout purposes.

Comment: Terry, you can't say like that. Prakash is right. because you may know all those things, but someone may not know those things. this is a place for sharing knowledge.